# This seems to just be filling up an array with the greatest number, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

```
def third_greatest(nums)
  idx = 0
  arr = []
  i = 1
  largest = 0
  while idx < nums.length
    while i < nums.length
        if nums[idx] > nums [i]
          largest = nums[idx]
        else
          largest = nums[idx]
        end
      i += 1
    end
  arr.push(largest)
  idx += 1
  i += idx
  end
  return arr[2]
end

puts(third_greatest([4, 3, 2, 1]) == 2)
#should equal true
```

I'm trying to get the third largest number out of the array but I keep getting four for any value of the array that returns data.
Any help would be great!

Comment: The third _greatest_ number in your example array is 3...not 2. 2 is the third _smallest_ number

Comment: The way I read the problem 4 is the greatest, 3 is the second greatest, and 2 is the third greatest.

Comment: Since `i` is non-decreasing (you only ever increment it), the innermost loop will only run the first time.

Comment: @Frxstrem you guys are right, I misread. I edited my answer to reflect the correction.

Comment: I thought since i is set back equal to idx + 1 at the bottom the while loop would run again...? (right or wrong?)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easier solution for finding the third greatest number in an array:

```
def third_greatest(nums)
    nums.sort!
    nums[-3]
end

third_greatest([4, 3, 2, 1])
=> 2

puts(third_greatest([4, 3, 2, 1]) == 2)
=> true
```

Comment: I'm just starting out so I don't know too much of the library and am just trying to master the basics, but thanks!

Comment: @Chris, No worries! Let me explain myself: the sort! method will sort an array from smallest to largest. The nums[-3] will access the third from last item in the sorted array ie the third largest/greatest number.

Answer (score 1):

at the end of the first time to the loop, **i** will be **nums.length**.

afterwards you increase **i** with **idx** so it is now bigger than **nums.length**.

In the next loops you will never enter the inner loop again, so the **largest** is never updated anymore.

That's why you always get **largest** in the result.

to fix it do something like :

```
  end
arr.push(largest)
idx += 1
i = idx + 1
```

end

so that **i** is reset to one higher than **idx**.

But the real solution is to leverage the rich standard library as Alex suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of [Enumerable#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) have allowed a parameter:

```
(0..9).to_a.max(3).last #=> 7
```

`max(n)` returns the three largest values, in decreasing magnitude. This could be expected to be more efficient than `sort` (unless `n == arr.size`, of course). Related `Enumerable` methods (`max_by`, `min`, `min_by`) also have this functionality.